# Force AWS Glue Crawler to create separate tables Instead of Partitions

Tags: aws-glue

I have a S3 bucket and that bucket has multiple Folders and each folder has like 500 files in it.
When I run the Crawler with the S3 URI which is like s3://my-bucket/ then it creates one single table and 628 partitions. I was expecting 628 tables instead.
s3://my-bucket/folder1/
s3://my-bucket/folder2/
....
s3://my-bucket/folder628/

When I give the **Table level** option in the Crawler as 1 or leave it empty it gives one table and 628 Partitions
When I give 2 it creates a table for each file inside the Folders

Can someone help me with it ?

Comment: What do you want to achieve with this job? Maybe I can help you skip the crawler part and use glue without it.

Comment: I want to load them to 628 different tables in Postgres. I want to read those files then create the structure in Postgres and then load the data to the Postgres DB.

Comment: Why not create a customized script to systematically read each file and then store the extracted data directly into a Postgres database? This approach provides complete control over the data processing flow, allowing for a tailored and efficient integration with the database.